# Is it possible to open an in-memory image using the python open function?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I am using a python library ([poster](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/poster/)) that takes a file-like object as an argument, the documentation states:

The file-like objects must support .read() and either .fileno() or both 
.seek() and .tell().

I have tried the library using the python `open` function and it works fine. I am currently downloading an image from a URL using the following:

```
access_token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
postPhotoUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=%s" % access_token

register_openers()

# get image from external URL
data = urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com/image.png")
data = StringIO(data.read())

### data, headers = multipart_encode({"source":open("file.png")}) <- WORKS FINE
data, headers = multipart_encode({"source":data})
request = urllib2.Request(postPhotoUrl,data,headers)
```

**EDIT: My goal is to fetch an image from an external URL and POST it using the facebook graph api. When I use the python `open` function I have no issues. When I try to use StringIO, no body is sent with the POST request.**

Comment: You have already found `StringIO`, which is itself a file-like object. So what's left to do here?

Comment: I really don't see what your problem is. I mean StringIO is already a file-like object that supports both seek() and tell().

Comment: it seems like an issue with the library then, can I convert the image to a File object that supports .read()

Comment: To be clear, a `StringIO` object supports `.read()`, `.seek()`, and `.tell()`.

Comment: @Thomas was referencing that the line you want is probably `data = StringIO(data.read())` ; there shouldn't be any need to download the .png image and then convert it into a PIL image object.

Comment: Actually, looking at the poster library and your line of questioning -- I think you're probably asking the wrong question and showing the wrong code.   Show us what you're doing with the poster library - exactly how are you encoding this image and making a request ? What is working and what isn't?  Poster seems to provide multiple facilities to encode parameters, you may be using it wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the idea is to use the [`poster`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/poster/) package to do a streaming HTTP upload, you shouldn't be converting the image data into a PIL `Image` object. Just do...

```
data = urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com/image.png")
data = StringIO(data.read())
```

...then you can pass the `data` variable to `poster`.

Unless, of course, you wanted to convert the image with PIL first, but you should probably mention that in your question.

**Update**

As for why it fails with a `StringIO`, it might be that `poster` is checking the filename of the open file, and using that to determine the correct `Content-Type` or somesuch, which it won't be able to do when reading from a `StringIO`.

I've never used the package, and the examples aren't very comprehensive, but it might be worth checking the difference between the `headers` variables when you call something like...

```
from poster.encode import multipart_encode

data = open('example.png', 'rb')
datagen, headers = multipart_encode({"image1": data})
```

...versus...

```
from poster.encode import multipart_encode

data = urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com/image.png")
data = StringIO(data.read())
datagen, headers = multipart_encode({"image1": data})
```

**Update #2**

Looks like I was right about the `Content-Type` thing. From the `poster` source code of `encode.py` lines 168-174...

```
        if hasattr(value, 'read'):
            # Looks like a file object
            filename = getattr(value, 'name', None)
            if filename is not None:
                filetype = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)[0]
            else:
                filetype = None
```

...although there may be other issues if `filename` is `None`. Try this...

```
from poster.encode import multipart_encode, MultipartParam

data = urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com/image.png")
data = StringIO(data.read())
param = MultipartParam(name='source',
                       filename='image.png',
                       filetype='image/png',
                       fileobj=data)
datagen, headers = multipart_encode({"source": param})
```

Comment: I have tried this approach already and poster sends an empty request, the only way I have been successful is using the python open function.

Comment: @S-K' Looks like you can specify some of the headers by using the [`MultipartParam`](http://atlee.ca/software/poster/poster.encode.html#poster.encode.MultipartParam) class.

Comment: Aya, I tried this and the headers were the same for both cases. Although the content-length was different. 278140 for open and 268822 for StringIO. Please see my updated answer for more clarity

Comment: @S-K' Well, the `Content-Length` discrepancy will be due to you not opening `file.png` in binary mode, so it'll insert carriage returns, which will corrupt the image. Change `open("file.png")` to `open("file.png", "rb")` to prevent that.

Comment: This seems like the correct solution but it seems the encoding made by the library must be wrong because facebook graph api is not accepting the request. It does accept the request when I use python open function though.

Comment: @S-K' Are you sure you have the latest version of the `poster` package? It looks like `StringIO` wasn't supported in older versions.

Comment: I am using 0.8.2 which I believe to be the latest. I pulled from bitbucket.

Comment: @S-K' Well, it sounds like a bug in the library. You could try [raising an issue](https://bitbucket.org/chrisatlee/poster/issues), fixing it yourself, or, since you don't seem to be using it in a streaming fashion, roll your own using Python's [`email`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email) module to do the multipart encoding.

Comment: You can use StringIO if you have it implement a 'name' property:
`my_file = StringIO('Hello, World!')` and then `my_file.name = 'file.txt'`